# What wrong with my php change password??? 

Tags: php

```
<? 
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{
header('Location: AdminLogin.php');
}
?>

<html lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLogin.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Welcome to ASM Services Inc.</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language=JavaScript>
var message="";
function clickIE() 
{
    if (document.all) 
    {(message);return false;}}
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="login">
<?php
require("adminconfig.inc");
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<form name=form1 method=post>
<table width=100 border=0 align=center>
<tr>
<font size=5 face=Arial color=yellow>Change Password</font>
</tr>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=4 face=Tahoma color=yellow>Username:</font></td>
        <td><input type=text name='username1' value='$user' size=20 AUTOCOMPLETE = off ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=4 face=Tahoma color=yellow>Password:</font></td>
        <td><input type=password name=password size=20 AUTOCOMPLETE = off></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=4 face=Tahoma color=yellow>New Password</font></td>
        <td><input type=password name=new_pass size=20 AUTOCOMPLETE = off></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=4 face=Tahoma color=yellow>Confirm Password:</font>:</td>
        <td><input type=password name=con_pass size=20 AUTOCOMPLETE = off></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=submit value=Ok name='btnCheck'>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=submit value=Cancel name=btnCancel onClick='this.form.reset()'>
    </tr>
</table>
</table>
</form>";
?>

<?php
require("adminconfig.inc");
$user = $_POST['username1'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$new_pass = trim($_POST['new_pass']);
$con_pass = trim($_POST['con_pass']);
if(isset($_POST['btnCheck']))
{
// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT Log_User, Log_Pass, User_Type FROM LOG_IN WHERE  
(Log_User = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username1']) . "') 
and 
(Log_Pass = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "') 
and 
(User_Type = 'member')") 
or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql"); ;


//Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) 
{
    if(trim('$new_pass') == trim('$con_pass'))
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE log_in SET Log_Pass='$new_pass' where username='$user'"); 
        if(!$sql) 
        { 
            echo "fail updating!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "success!";
            echo "<script type = text/javascript>";
            echo "alert('The new password has been changed successfully.');";
            echo "</script>";
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fail!";
        echo "<script type = text/javascript>";
        echo "alert('Error. New Password and Confirm Password are not the same. Please make it sure that they are the same.');";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
}
?>

</div>

<div class="copyright">
&copy; Copyright 2011 <strong>ASM Services Inc.</strong>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my whole code for changing the password of the user. I really don't what's the exact error of my code. Whenever I change the password, it always brings to the "Error. New Password and Confirm Password are not the same".

Comment: this is indeed a "too localized" question

Comment: You're storing the password in **plaintext**; that's the single *most* wrong thing in your code. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: I won't say it's *most* wrong thing. Personally I don't mind if my password were stored in plain text. To register on some lame site I'd use mailinator and care not of it's security

Comment: How did the word "help" make it into the title? Isn't there a filter for that?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Well, *you* may be using a different, reasonably secure password for every site; alas, that is not a very typical case. With password reuse, I fear that Joe R. User will enter the same password for a lame site as for his e-mail account and his banking account. Note that the user's e-mail address is usually stored nearby in most databases.

Comment: @Piskvor as long as you don't care for the password strength, all this hashing mess is just a baby talk. It is interesting phenomenon of this blessed site - among numerous security issues, only hashing were chosen to peddle with.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Good point - if the password is `12345`, then the security of the backend becomes somewhat moot. (I didn't say that's the *only* problem of the code :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code has:

```
if(trim('$new_pass') == trim('$con_pass')) {
  // passwords match
} else {
  // passwords don't match
}
```

You are comparing the strings `'$new_pass'` & `'$con_pass'` and not the variables `$new_pass` & `$con_pass`. Also don't use should not use `trim` as the user might have space in his passwords.

Change

```
if(trim('$new_pass') == trim('$con_pass'))
```

to

```
if($new_pass == $con_pass)
```

Also you read the passwords from the form as:

```
$new_pass = trim($_POST['new_pass']);
$con_pass = trim($_POST['con_pass']);
```

You should not be using `trim` here as well. If the user wants to have space at the end/beginning of his password, your logic will fail as the user thinks his password has the space but the password you enter in the DB will not have space.

Comment: thank you for reminding me.. when I changed my codes, then next error I get is "fail updating".. what do you think my error?? thanks again

Comment: @Kevzz There must be something wrong with your sql. Try seeing the error by doing a var_dump(mysql_error()); after the echo "fail updating";

Comment: @Jeune, thank you for giving me that code.. I knew the error of my code.. And its now working.. :D Thank a lot God bless :D

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if(trim('$new_pass') == trim('$con_pass'))
```

to

```
if(trim($new_pass) == trim($con_pass))
```

Comment: -1 codaddict already [said that ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075820/what-wrong-with-my-php-change-password-pls-help/8075842#8075842)